# How manipulate ERA5 land hourly data with Python?

Tags: python, jupyter, era5

I recently started to use **ERA5 land-hourly** data and python code.

I will use data of 2 variables (*total precipitation* and *2 metre temperature*) from an entire year (2017).

Data downloaded are in GRIB or netCDF format.

The things I want to do are:

**1) Convert units**. In the case of:

- Total precipitation - convert "m" into "mm"
- 2m temperature      - convert "Kelvin" into "Celsius"

**2) Convert hourly to daily values**:

I've found the following code from ECMWF's offficial site:
https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5%3A+How+to+calculate+daily+total+precipitation
Unfortunately, the code is designed only to compile daily values for one day 
(January 1st, 2017).

I want to convert all values for an entirely year. I know that (*if I'm right*):

- total precipitation presents acumulated values. So daily value is the sum of 24 hours.
- temperature presents mean values. So daily value is the mean of 24 hours.

**3) Pick especific information from data files**:

In order to do an analysis, I want to keep only information about:

- values
- latitude
- longitude
- time

for both variables (total precipitation and 2 metre temperature)

**4) Convert GRIB or netCDF files into some format that can be read by Stata software**

I really will appreciate any gesture of help

Comment: For the tasks 1-3, the best tool would be cdo (climate data operators). The tasks can be done with a single command. I have no clue about sdata. I guess, more or less standard  (i.e. compliant with CF-conventions) output of cdo should do.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these tasks are easy to do if you use [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/)

1) Unit conversion:

```
import xarray as xr 
ds = xr.open_dataset(path/to/netcdf/file)

# converting total precipitation from m to mm
ds.tp = ds.tp * 1000

# converting t2m from K to C
ds.t2m = ds.t2m - 273.15
```

2) Hourly to Daily data:

xarray [.resample](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html?highlight=resample#xarray.Dataset.resample) method can help you here.

```
# daily temperature mean from hourly values
ds.t2m.resample(time='1D').mean()
# daily precipitation sum from hourly values
ds.tp.resample(time='1D').sum()
```

Your points 3) and 4) should be better explained to increase your chances of getting proper help

Comment: Hi @igrolvr ! Thanks for your comment. I used the codes for unit conversion and rearranged them. I have a doubt that I posted as a new question,  the link is  (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58964781/12375837). The points 3 and 4, I'll clarify later.

Comment: Hi @igrolvr and Brian. I want to do something very similar to what have been discussed here. But, after steps 1 and 2, I would like to have a simple pandas dataframe with columns Date, Lat, Longitude, T2 Daily Max, T2 Daily Sum, t2 Daily Min and Total Precipitation. Is there a way to accomplish that (convert de ds above to pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

ERA5-Land Hourly precipitation and ERA5 Reanalysis Hourly precipitation are different.  See https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=197702790 and refer to the Hydrological parameter table. ERA5 Reanalysis Hourly and ERA5-Land Hourly have quite different specifications of how to extract daily totals.
For ERA5-Land Hourly the precipitation values are totals since the beginning of each day. ERA5 Reanalysis Hourly precipitation are totals for the hour.
This means that daily totals from ERA5-Land Hourly are not the sum of the precipitation values for each hour, but is the precipitation value for the 00 hour of the next day.

Comment: This is [data](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land?tab=overview). I guess the total precipitation variable refers to ERA 5 - Land hourly data in the link you provided, am I right?

Comment: The link I provided shows the applicable dataset in the left hand column called "Dataset". It is the fifth row you need for calculation details of ERA5 - Land hourly precipitation accumulation